# Is Qt5 designer available for linux?

Tags: linux, qt

I installed Qt library and Qt creator in Linux Mint but when I try to run the designer I get the following error:

```
designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer': No such file or directory
```

I cannot find the designer version 5 online, but I could find the version 4. I'm afraid that this older version could not handle all the Qt5 new features.

Is the Qt designer version 5 available for Linux?

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: @user877329 Mint 17.2

Comment: you're trying to run the designer from inside Qt Creator?

Comment: I think Mint is based on Ubuntu LTS, which currently is 14.04. This version may lack some Qt5 packages. With the next LTS you go, or switch to 15.10 in between.

Comment: @danielfranca I tried from command line. I don't know how to do it from the Qt Creator. In any case, the Qt designer binary is simply not present in the folder

Comment: @HAL9000 The designer is integrated into the QtCreator, never tried to run it by itself in Qt5 though.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-using-qt-quick-designer.html

Comment: @danielfranca in QtCreator I don't have the Form menu and I cannot see the preview of my ui. I tried to reinstall Qt but still I have the same issue.

Comment: Please check whether you've installed the `libqt5designer5` package or not. `dpkg --status libqt5designer5`

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto it says Status: install ok installed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The designer app is part of the `qttools5-dev-tools` package:

You can find the solution to answers like "where can I get binary X from" in Debian-based distros quite easily:

```
% apt-file search bin/designer                                                                          
qt4-designer: /usr/bin/designer-qt4
qt4-designer: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer
qt4-designer: /usr/share/qt4/bin/designer
qtchooser: /usr/bin/designer
qttools5-dev-tools: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

`qtchooser` just provides a wrapper for the *designer* binary, it will start either Qt4 or Qt5-based designer.

`qt4-designer` & `qttools5-dev-tools` contain the real binary. You can choose.

Comment: Just noticed: now you may ask where you get the `apt-file` binary from. It's in the `apt-file` package. I can only recommend it, highly useful for searching the Debian/Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Qt using the installers provided by the Qt website, the designer can also be launched from
    `~/Qt/<VERSION>/<COMPILER>/bin/designer`